# Zend Framework Autoloader question

Tags: php, zend-framework

In zend framework I register my namespace like this (in application.php):

```
'autoloaderNamespaces' => array(
    'Cms_'
)
```

And after this - I'd expect that Zend would always check that path in addition to Zend and ZendX paths if unknown class is called. But for some reason this doesn't work with for example view helpers.

I still have to register a separate path for my view helpers even though view helper scripts are named according to Zend coding standards and are located  in:

```
Cms/View/Helper/
```

And this is how I register helper path in config file:

```
view' => array(
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'doctype' => 'XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL',
    'helperPath' => array(
        'Cms_View_Helper_' => 'Cms/View/Helper'
        )
),
```

So - I'm not sure why I have to register "Cms" namespace twice first through 'autoloaderNamespaces' and then through View "helperPath"? Shouldn't Cms namespace include Cms/View/Helper namespace?

can someone plz clarify this:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is exactly as you describe, the [documentation on custom view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom) is pretty explicit about it:

> You may, and should, give the class name a prefix, and it is recommended that you use 'View_Helper' as part of that prefix: "My_View_Helper_SpecialPurpose". (You will need to pass in the prefix, with or without the trailing underscore, to addHelperPath() or setHelperPath()).

This does make some sense to me though. In theory you could build a library of generic view helpers that could be re-used across multiple applications, so binding them to a specific application namespace would be inconvenient, i.e. if all my helpers were prefixed 'MyApp_' I would have to rename them to be able to use them in 'MyOtherApp'.

Answer (score 4):

View Helpers are considered application specific, so in the [Recommended Project Directory Structure](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html) View Helpers are supposed to be placed in application/views/helpers. Which means, they usually wouldn't be found if ZF would just resolve the conventionalized class name.

When you call helpers with `$this->helperName()` or `$this->getHelper('HelperName')` from the View, the View will use the PluginLoader with the configured prefix and path to fetch that helper and inject the current View Instance. See sourcecode for all the details:

- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php
- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php

So in other words, when loading a ViewHelper, you are not using the Autoloader. See:

- [Loading Plugins in the Zend Framework Reference Guide](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.loader.pluginloader.html)

Comment: @gordon - how do you know so much about zend framework? :) Do you know every class by heart?  I'm just curious cuz i'm preparing for Zend Framework certification.

Comment: @Andre I dont know *that* much about ZF. I usually just check the reference guide for the obvious and if that's not explaining it, I check with the sourcecode.

Comment: and that's a whole lot of source code checking given current state of zend documentation:)

Comment: @Andre I hear that complaint often but don't think the guide and API docs are too shabby. Most of the time I don't need to dive into the sourcecode. It's usually only when I want to understand *why* a component works a certain way, but not when I need to figure *how* to use a component.

Comment: @Gordon: Same here ;) I don't understand the complaints at all. BTW: Really liked your post ;)

Comment: ohhh. c'mon you guys. you truthfully frankly don't see the difference between Codeigniter docs and Zend docs? seriously:)? even zf creators acknowledge that there is a problem:   http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Proposal+for+Documentation+in+ZF2

Comment: @Andre Tbh, I never understood why people think CI docs are supposed to be so great. IIRC they dont even have API docs. And going through the CI code is even less pleasant than going through ZF code.

Answer (score 2):

This is taken directly from one of my application.ini files.

```
autoloaderNamespaces.Foo = "Foo"
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

My "Foo" libraries are in the library directory - library/Foo. All I've done up until this point is make the "Foo" library available within the include paths.

I need to add a separate helper path to the default list for my view, otherwise the view won't look in that directory for matching view helpers. I think of loading view helpers as direct discovery. The view needs explicit instructions on where to look for helpers.